# Docker container setup understanding

Tags: docker, mosquitto

After getting issues with a running container in docker, i would like to understand the options a bit better.

I've been working with eclipse mosquitto. It was running quite well until yesterday. After looking into the logs, I've found out that mosquitto can't find the password file anymore. And now my issue starts

- Where can I find the config folder of mosquitto in docker?
- How can I change the config (Where to find or howto access it)
- How can I specify the location for config, data and logs?

Does anybody has got a short description? I mean this one here is nice, by what do I really have to do to get it running?

https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-mosquitto

Do I need to create folder there for the config? And where????

Comment: The first 2 sections in that link cover this about as clearly as it's possible to. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62387716/edit) the question to point out which bits you specifically have a problem with. The directories mentioned are inside the container and already exist.

Comment: That edit doesn't really help. To have been running with a password file, you must have been passing in a custom config file already. Edit the question to show how you were starting the container and the config files you are using so we can see what you are working with.

Comment: Yes, I know, have the same issue that it does not really help. I have used an ready configuration from some stack, but this does not help to understand, how docker really works. and now I guess, I have deleted the volume with the config from portainer as it was shown as unused.. I have created a new container in meanwhile and this one works, but again, how can I access the config of mosquitto?

Answer (score 2):

To answer the 3 questions:

- The default `mosquitto.conf` file is in `/mosquitto/config`
- You mount your own `mosquitto.conf` file over the default one found in `/mosquitto/config` directory
- You can not change the location of the config file. You can specify where the logs and persistence data is stored in the config file. But there is no good reason to change it from the `/mosquitto/data` or `/mosquitto/log`

All 3 of those answers came from the doc you linked to.

If you want to read the default `mosquitto.conf` you can find it on github [here](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/mosquitto.conf)